# Como exportar reportes .jasper a formato excel

Tags: java, excel, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

No he podido encontrar la solución para poder exportar un reporte a excel. Pero si pude  exportarlo en formato pdf.

```
    File reportfile = new File(application.getRealPath("inventario.jasper"));
    Map<String,Object> parameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    
    //String valor = request.getParameter("txtparametro");
    //parameter.put("mar",new String(valor));
    
    byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter, con);
    
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputstream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    
    outputstream.flush();
    outputstream.close();
```

Todo lo anterior incluyendo la conexión están hechos dentro de mi proyecto web aplicattion en archivos .jsp y quisiera que la exportacion en excel tambien este en un .jsp.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Qué versión de jasperreports y de iReport estás usando?

Comment: Jasperreports version 6.0.0 y iReport 5.5.0 :/